# Application Insights wrong ip address

Tags: azure, geolocation, ip, azure-application-insights

I am using Application Insights to track my user location, but I run into this error:
running my code locally works fine, but as soon as I deploy my application on Azure, my user location is always the same as the server location.

I look around for a solution, but can't find any clear solution.
Anyone any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: that implies to me that either (a) the server is the only thing with application insights instrumented, you don't have any instrumentation in the "client" part (the web page itself, using the AI javascript sdk?)  or (2)your inbound requests are not properly getting the ip address from the client. does something on the network proxy requests so the inbound requests appear to all be from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

There are two different things here:

If your service / application is instrumented with AI and hosted on Azure then and if you see the incoming request on that service you should see the IP address of the client when you look into the details on analytics portal.

If your service sends telemetry data using some track() API then that would ofcourse get the ip of the location where the service is deployed.

So it depends on what you are looking at.

Comment: I am looking for the client IP

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your server sits behind a reverse proxy and needs forwarded headers.
Try this in your startup:

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions{ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto});
```